# Redirect / reload browser

Tags: javascript

I want to display popup window that closes once user is auhenticated and redirects user to home page. For backward compatibility login page can display in browser and not in popu window.

index.jsp

```
<%--@elvariable id="USER" type="cz.literak.demo.oauth.model.entity.User"--%>
<c:if test="${not empty USER}">
    <p>
        Logged as ${USER.firstName} ${USER.lastName}, <a href="logout">Logout</a>
        <c:if test="${not USER.areRegistered('TW,FB,GG')}">
            <a href="login.jsp" class="popup" data-width="600" data-height="400">Improve Login</a>
        </c:if>
    </p>
</c:if>
<c:if test="${empty USER}">
    <p>
        <a href="login.jsp" class="popup" data-width="600" data-height="400">Login</a>
    </p>
</c:if>
<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script>
    $("a.popup").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        window.open (href, "OAUTHLOGIN", "height=" + height +",width=" + width + "");
    });
</script>
```

Once authenticated, popup/browser is redirected to logged.jsp. It shall redirect main window to home page and close popup window, if login.jsp was opened in it.

```
<script>
    window.top.location = "index.jsp";
    if (window.name == "OAUTHLOGIN") {
        window.close();
    }
</script>
```

It seems to be working with one exception. If browser already displays index.jsp, then nothing happens. I tried `location.reload(true)`, but it caused infinite loop in popup instead.

How can I make it work? Thanks

Comment: does window.top.location.reload work?

Comment: no, popup closed, but original page remained unaffected.

Comment: I assume there are signs that you can tell if the page has refreshed? Something like when the user is logged in, it shows their username or something like that

Comment: Exactly, there is login link instead of user name and logout link

Comment: is this all of the code? if there are more, can you put it up please. Can you also insert some test statements to check the window you are trying to reload is the one you are expecting

Comment: more code, the rest is html boilerplate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use;

```
<script>
    // Get parent url
    var parent_url = window.parent.location.href;
    // Check parent if it has "index.php"
    if (parent_url.match(/index.jsp/g) || parent_url.match(/.com\//g)) { // yoursite.com/
        // if it is, reload parent window
        window.opener.location.reload(false);
    } else {
        // Else go to index.php
        window.top.location = "index.jsp";
    }

    if (window.name == "OAUTHLOGIN") {
            window.close();
    }
</script>
```

**Edit:**
Another possible solution:
When user logged in, just refresh parent window. In your system, you need to check if user logged in or not in an interceptor like something. When parent window refreshed, if user logged in, it will be redirected to registered area, else it will redirected to login page if current page is registered page. In your `loggedin.jsp`, you can only use;

```
<script>
    window.opener.location.reload(false);
    if (window.name == "OAUTHLOGIN") {
            window.close();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I will try but if condition must be different. The url does not need to contain index.jsp, slash / is possible as well.

Comment: There were missing parentheses in match methods. Nevertheless parent window is not refreshed. You can try it there: http://www.literak.cz:8080/OAuthLogin/

Comment: Thanks, I did not notice updated section. And it worked!